# R equivalent of Python's range() function

Tags: r

Is there an R equivalent to Python's range function?

In Python I can do this:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(i)

1
2
3
```

and **especially** this:

```
for i in range(1, 0):
    print(i)

# prints nothing!
```

Meanwhile in R:

```
> 1:0

[1] 1 0
```

also

```
> c(1:0)

[1] 1 0
```

and

```
> seq(from=1, to=0)

[1] 1 0
```

I need a function that given as input a *min* and a *max*
returns a vector of increasing integers from *min* to *max* s.t. if *max < min* returns an empty vector.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666940/is-there-an-r-function-equivalent-to-range-in-python) on SO is different from mine. Talks about strings and `seq()` which, as shown above, is not equivalent to `range()`.

Comment: As far as I can tell `seq` simply *never* generates an empty sequence, except when invoked on an empty vector.

Comment: See `?sequence`. For example `sequence(from = 1, 3)`; `sequence(from = 1, 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent. As noted, `seq` doesn't work because the `by` argument is automatically set with the correct sign, and generates an error if you try to explicitly pass a positive sign when `to < from`. Just create a very simple wrapper if you need to have the exact match.

```r
py_range <- function(from, to) {
  if (to <= from) return(integer(0))
  seq(from = from, to = to - 1)
}

py_range(1, 4)
#> [1] 1 2 3
py_range(1, 0)
#> integer(0)
py_range(1, 1)
#> integer(0)
```

These will work in a loop with printing as you desire.

```r
for (i in py_range(1, 4)) {
  print(i)
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3

for (i in py_range(1, 0)) {
  print(i)
}
#> Nothing was actually printed here!

for (i in py_range(1, 1)) {
  print(i)
}
#> Nothing was actually printed here!
```

Answer (score 0):

seq works well in this case:

```
> x <- NULL
> for (i in seq(x)) print(i)
> #
```

Thanks